# required attribute does not check whether ng-model is in the selectable options

Tags: angularjs, html, forms, validation, angularjs-ng-model

I have a form in my AngularJS app where an account can select and update values, let's say VendorID and ProductID.  Each of those values is set in a select box, with the current vendor driving the allowed values in the product dropdown.  When the user changes the value of the vendor, then the page loads an array of products applicable to that vendor.

```
<div style="margin-top: 10px;">
    Select vendor:
    <select name="vendorID" ng-model="vendorID" ng-options="vendor.id as vendor.name for vendor in vendors" ng-change="loadProducts()" required></select>
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 10px;">
    Select product:
    <select name="productID" ng-model="productID" ng-options="product.id as product.name for product in products" required></select>
</div>
```

I have the `required` attribute both select boxes but it only appears to check whether the underlying ng-model value is non-null, not whether it is one of the available options. Changing the vendor value puts the new values in the product select box, but even none of them are selected the `form.productID.$valid` property is still `true` and the form is submittable.  Should the `required` attribute not catch this, or is it only looking at the `ng-model` value?

What ends up happening is the user can then hit Save, and the vendor and product are out of sync. I could null/zero out the product ID when the vendor value changes, but in actuality these select boxes go several levels deep, and I would like to preserve the user's original values in case they want to set them back without having to re-select everything.

Is there a way to have `required` check whether one of the *current* options is selected?

I have created an example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ngmgyaHOQzLv53TjfqHV?p=preview).  Changing the vendor "empties" the product select, but does not change validity.  If the `$scope.productID` is initialized to `null` then the validation works as expected.

Comment: It only looks for `ng-model` You would need to create your own validation directive and invalidate validity... Or nullify `ng-model` itself from the controller when the it is not among the list.

Comment: Well, that definitely appeared to be what was going on. I was just hoping there maybe was a nuance to it all that I'm overlooking.

Comment: ng-model controller has a property called [$validators](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$validators) which you can use to push your validation rule so that it is automatically extecuted as a part of angular validation.

Comment: OK, I'll check it out. I've added functions to the `$parsers` property for my Angular 1.2 code - looks like $validators are the way to go for 1.3.  Thanks.

Comment: oh yes, they are added from 1.3 onwards... $parsers should work for you then.